# Use Prolog to bind a letter to a given integer such as in class grades

Tags: prolog, syntax-error, constraints, bind, function-call

I need to use Prolog to bind a letter grade for a given integer grade value (>= 90 is a, >= 80 is b, and so on.)

I am trying to write a function such as this:

```
evaluate_grade( X ,   F   ) :- X \>= 0.0 , X \< 2.0 .
```

But in the query window:

```
evaluate_grade(.1,F)
```

I get:

```
Cannot run query due to a syntax error (check query window)

Syntax error: Operator expected
```

What am I missing here?

I just want to enter one number and get a letter like: `evaluate_grade(1) -> F`.

Comment: You are mising a dot (`.`) at the end of your query and a 0 before .1 (`evaluate_grade(0.1,F).`). Also the head of your rule should be f or `'F'`.

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  But I just want to enter one number and get a letter like: evaluate_grade(1)->F

Answer (score 1):

1. Your query, `evaluate_grade(.1,F)` is missing the terminating period, so it is syntactically incorrect.
2. `.1` is not a numeric literal in the Prolog language: An integer component is required for a numeric literal.

   `0.1` is a numeric literal while `.1` is syntactically incorrect — `.` is the predicate `./2`, and is defined as an infix operator. There's nothing to bind with to the left of the `.` so the parse fails.
3. Your predicate:

   ```
   evaluate_grade( X ,   F   ) :- X \>= 0.0 , X \< 2.0 .
   ```

   is going to give you another warning regarding singleton variables: Any identifier beginning with a capital letter is a variable. Your predicate will succeed, but since nothing is unified with `F`, it will remain unbound.
4. `\` is the negation operator, so `\>=` is a clumsy way of saying `<`, and `\<` is a clumsy way of saying `>=`.

If you change your predicate to this:

```
evaluate_grade( X , f ) :- X >= 0.0 , X < 2.0 .
```

and query it:

```
?- evaluate_grade( 0.1 , G ) .
```

You'll get

```
G = f
```

See the playground at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/NDsZkKSg.pl

Regarding your comment:

> OK. Thanks. But I just want to enter one number and get a letter like: `evaluate_grade(1)->F`

Prolog does not have functions and there are not return values. Whatever you want "returned" is passed as an argument. You pass in an *uninstantiated* variable, and when the proof is completed and the control flow gets back to you, the variable becomes instantiated to a minimal conformant value, as needed for the query to hold.

Given your definition of `evaluate_grade/2`, querying `evaluate_grade(1)` will fail, since the predicate doesn't exist. And if it did, it could only succeed or fail. There's no means for it to "return" anything in an additional argument, as there are no additional arguments in your predicate.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks.  What about an error message if what is entered is not a number such as: evaluate_grade( blahblah , G ) .

Answer (score 0):

Possible method:

```
grade(90, a).
grade(80, b).
grade(70, c).
grade(60, d).
grade(50, e).
grade(40, f).
grade(30, g).
grade(20, h).
grade(10, i).
grade(0, j).

eval_grade(I, G) :-
    grade(N, G),
    (   G == a
    ->  Inc = 10
    ;   Inc = 9
    ),
    U is N + Inc,
    (   ground(I)
    ->  between(N, U, I),
        % Prevent backtracking after the 1 solution
        !
    ;   between(N, U, I)
    ).
```

... which has nice features:

```
% The most general query works
?- eval_grade(I, G).
I = 90,
G = a ;
etc.

% No unwanted choicepoint, if given the score
?- eval_grade(14, G).
G = i.

?- eval_grade(100, G).
G = a.

% If given just the grade, loops through the scores
?- eval_grade(I, e).
I = 50 ;
etc.
```